# geometry - Footnotes immediately after text

Tags: footnotes, typography, geometry, book-design

The package `geometry` makes it very easy to define how much space should separe the text from the footnotes:

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{footnotesep=2em}
```

However the setting is effective only when the page's body is filled with text, while I'd like it to work as well when the page is mainly blank (see page 4 in the MWE), something that often occurs in the end of book chapters.

I could not find any help in the [geometry documentation](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/geometry/geometry.pdf#subsection.5.5), but I guess it is my fault as I am just at the beginning in my exploration of LaTeX's possibilities from a more 'code-conscious' point of view.

**Edit.** One comment suggests using the [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/593014/212292) presented in a related question (see link at the bottom). When setting the spacing to 2em inside the renewed footnote (`\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vfilneg\vspace{2em}\svfootnoterule}`) the job is done indeed, but the text leaks out of the page body:

[image: Text leaking]

If, instead, I set `geometry`'s `footnotesep` to 2em, and ask for no space in the renewed command (`\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vfilneg\svfootnoterule}`), again the spacing is the wanted one on mainly blank ending pages, but it then becomes random throughout the document (highlighted in pink in the picture below):

[image: Uneven spacing]

I've addes a second MWE with more text, so that the problem with this solution become a tad more clear, though I could not make them as bold as in the book I'm working on, from wich I took the pictures.

---

MWE (original)

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\geometry{showframe,footnotesep=2em}
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\rule{\linewidth}{0pt}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]\section*{Section}\lipsum[2-5] Text\footnote{Foot text note.}\section*{Another}\lipsum[1]
\newpage
%this is how I'd like it:
\lipsum[1]\section*{Section}\lipsum[2-5] Text\textsuperscript{1}\section*{Another}\lipsum[1]\vspace{2em}

{\noindent\footnotesize\quad\textsuperscript{1}Foot text note.} %approximate indentation

\end{document}
```

---

MWE (more text, adapted from Simon Dispa's answer)

```
\begin{document}
1.  \lipsum[1] Text\footnote{\, 7. \lipsum[1-2]}  % full page
    
    \section*{Section 1}
    
2.  \lipsum[2-5] Text\footnote{\, 8. \lipsum[1-2]}% unfilled page
    \section*{Another 1}
3.  \lipsum[1]
    \raggedbottom\clearpage
%   \newpage
    %this is how I'd like it:
4.  \lipsum[1]
    \section*{Section 2}
    
5.  \lipsum[2-5]Text\footnote{\, 9. \lipsum[7]} % unfilled page
        
    \section*{Another 2}
6.  \lipsum[1]

7. \lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[1]}\lipsum[2]\footnote{\lipsum[2]}\lipsum[3-6]\footnote{\lipsum[1]}
```

Related: [Footnotes immediately after text on mainly blank pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593010/footnotes-immediately-after-text-on-mainly-blank-pages)

Comment: The solution of  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/593010/footnotes-immediately-after-text-on-mainly-blank-pages works fine if you use  `\raggedbottom\clearpage` instead of `\newpage`. And also at the end of the document replacing `Text\textsuperscript{1}` for  `Text\footnote{Foot text note.}`

Comment: `\geometry{footnotesep=0em}` combined with `\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vfilneg\vspace{2em}\svfootnoterule}` does the job but makes the footnotes leak out of the page body. `\geometry{footnotesep=2em}` combined with `\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vfilneg\vspace{0em}\svfootnoterule}` produces inconsistent spacing throughout the document

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Keep me posted.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** Using the new MWE.

I added some "numbers" to help identify sections and paragraphs, and a `1em` spaced grid.

*The length that determines the distance between text body and footnotes* is `\skip\footins`, set here as `\setlength{\skip\footins}{2em}`

(`\footnotesep` determines the height of the struts separating the footnotes)

LaTeX does not print on a grid. However, as you can see in the figures below,
the space between the text and the first footnote is (very) close to `2em`, for both full pages and partially filled pages.

**#1 full page**
[image: 1]

**#2 page not filled**
[image: 2]

**#3 page filled**

[image: 3]

**#5 last page, not filled**

[image: 5]

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\gridpaper}{% draw a grid spaced 1em
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[line width=.4pt,draw=black!30] (0,0) grid[step=1em] (\paperwidth,\paperheight);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{background}
\backgroundsetup{%
    angle=0,
    contents=\gridpaper,
    scale=1,
}

\setlength{\skip\footins}{2em} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vfilneg} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    1.  \lipsum[1] FULL PAGE\footnote{\, 12. \lipsum[1-2]}  % full page
    
    \section*{Section 1}
    
    3.  \lipsum[2-3] TEXT\footnote{\, 4. \lipsum[1-2]}% unfilled page
    \section*{Another 1}
    5.  \lipsum[1]  (PAGE NOT FILLED)   

    \raggedbottom\clearpage
    %   \newpage
    %this is how I'd like it:
    6.  \lipsum[1]
    \section*{Section 2}
    
    7.  \lipsum[2-5] FULL PAGE\footnote{\, 8. \lipsum[7]}
    
    \section*{Another 2}

    9.  \lipsum[1]  
    10. \lipsum[1]\footnote{11. \, \lipsum[3]}% \rule{1pt}{2em}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}     
    12. \lipsum[2]\footnote{13. \, \lipsum[2]}
    14. \lipsum[4-5]\footnote{15. \, \lipsum[1]}  (LAST PAGE, NOT FILLED)   

\end{document
```

Comment: Try adding `\lipsum[1]\footnote{\lipsum[1]}\lipsum[2]\footnote{\lipsum[2]}\lipsum[3-6]\footnote{\lipsum[1]}` with `footnotesep=2em` (I need a 2em spacing!) and `\renewcommand\footnoterule{\vfilneg\svfootnoterule}`, and see how the last three footnotes are differently spaced from the text. I'm adding a picture to the question where this is even more evident. Thank you.

Comment: @Mattia I updated the answer using your new MWE. Please try the new code.

Comment: Strangely this does work when compiled on its own, but fails (i.e. text is left at the bottom) when I implement it in the main document. I'll try to solve and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: I managed to make it work, but there still are some issues with the spacing. In the meantime I'll upvote your answer. I will update the question in some days; thank you for your help!